# Tmux: pane border characters crooked line

Tags: terminal, tmux

I have started to use tmux and noticed that the lines that seperate the different panes are not entirely straight, instead there are small bumps. I think it might have something to do with the font, my thought is that characters from one "character-field" are overlapping into the next, which creates the little bumps. Does anyone know how I can fix this and get a straight line without bumps?
The font I use: Menlo
[example of the bumpy lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7poc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually the terminal emulator I used, Alacritty, which lets some characters reach outside of their cell. To solve this issue, I switched to [Kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/), which has better support for preventing characters from overflowing into other cells.